# Why can't I adopt kids despite already having killed Grelod the Kind?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I want to adopt kids in Skyrim (on Xbox). I have the Hearthfire DLC, and also have killed Grelod the Kind. I walk in to the orphanage and Constance Michel is just doing things regularly and won't talk to me. I have a house in Whiterun with a children's room.

Any idea why I can't adopt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adopt kids,there's one in katlas farm (Blaise) and one who usually sits next to the tree in whiterun (Lucia).Theres a few more (1 in every hold atleast) Happy child hunting!

Comment: Not every hold. There are 4 kids you can adopt in 4 holds.

Comment: I'm going to edit this

Comment: I Adopted those same 2 during my first run. Every run since I've adopted Alesan(Redguard boy in Dawnstar) and Sophie(flower girl in Windhelm). They seemed like they have a rougher time of things. Blaise  can sleep on the hay in the stable in a a part of the hold with better weather, Lucia has Brenuin to look out for her and sometimes sleeps on a bench by the tree. Sophia sleeps on a concrete slab outside Niranye's house, and Alesan says they let him sleep by the fire in the inn sometimes. He works hard. Both Dawnstar and Windhelm have worse weather than Solitude and Whiterun.

Answer (score 9):

First, you must go to Windhelm and talk to [Aventus Aretino](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Aventus_Aretino).

He will reward you for killing Grelod. After this, you will receive a letter from a courier, from the Dark Brotherhood. This begins the quest "[With Friends Like These...](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/With_Friends_Like_These...)."

After you get this note, sleep in a bed. You will be abducted by the Dark Brotherhood. After this, you either need to join the Brotherhood or kill Astrid.

After completing this, you should be able to adopt children.

Comment: @bubblyGaming18 If I helped you, please click the grey checkmark by the answer. Once it turns green, it'll be marked as your question's answer, and will help others get their answer faster! (Plus, it gives you reputation!)

Answer (score 2):

After you are inducted into the dark brotherhood, you can get them. Steps below

1: get inducted

2: become thane, and build your house

3: go to the orphanage and adopt a child (after you get the letter stating that Michele has taken over the orphanage)

MAKE SURE YOU HAVE A HOUSE BUILT WITH CHILDERN'S BEDS TOO, OR YOU CAN'T ADOPT A CHILD